# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'connect'

Tags: python, database, sqlite, connection, database-connection

I'm trying to insert data into my already created sqlite3 database. The data is able to be inputted. However, when trying to connect to my database and save I receive an error saying "  AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'connect'"
My code fragment is listed below:

```
def data_entry():
    option_choice=0
    call("clear")
    print"\t","\n"*4
    print"\t","-"*45
    print"\t","\t-- Data Entry --"

    ID = raw_input("what is your user ID?")
    Name = raw_input("What is your name?")
    Age = raw_input("how old are you?")
    incidents = raw_input("How many incidents have you been involved in?")
    physical_ability = raw_input("what is your physical driving state?")
    Address = raw_input("what is your address?")
    Tel = raw_input("what is your phone number?")
    datestamp = raw_input("What is today's date?")
    keyword = raw_input("What is the make of your vehicle?")
    monthly_salary = raw_input("How much do you earn each month?")

    conn = db.connect('Insurance_Shark.db') 
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO customerdatabase VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
        (ID, Name, Age, incidents, physical_ability, Address, Tel, datestamp, keyword, monthly_salary))
```

Comment: show you `import` line and what `db` in `db.connect` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown how the `db` variable is defined, but it looks like *it is a function*, because:

```
>>> def db():
...     pass
... 
>>> db.connect()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'connect'
```

The [`connect()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect) is available directly from the `sqlite3` module:

```
>>> import sqlite3 
>>> sqlite3.connect("test.db")
<sqlite3.Connection object at 0x10d922a28>
```